# Unexpected behaviour of Typescript Record<number, Type> type

Tags: typescript

I was playing around with the `Record` type, when I found out something which wasn't what I was expected to be. I am in Typescript 5.16.

If I have a `Record<string, T>` type, and I have this object

```
const a: Record<string, T> = {
  123: someData,
  x: someData
}
```

Then this works. This is probably because in javascript, number indices on objects are actually coerced to string, so this is somewhat an expected behaviour.
However, if I add a `symbol` type as a key, it does not error at all (and to my knowledge, `symbol`s don't get coerced to anything). Even if I have a `Record<number, T>`, it accepts symbols as keys along with only numeric indices.
What even more confuses me is that if I do something like

```
const a: Record<number, T> = {
  123: someData,
  [Symbol.for("ABCD")]: someData
}
```

it compiles perfectly fine, but if I give a pre built symbol instead, like `Symbol.iterator` (only when key type is `number` as the last example), it errors as expected. [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAWlC8UBKEDGB7ATgEwDwDsBXAWwCMJMAaKAZ2EwEt8BzAPgG4AoTjfOqAF4AuWAigBvTlCgAmEQCIAhvMpSoAbQDKIMugA2AOgBmWABTyAgvICUAXQUqoAeidR86KBUxYoACwoQauoAjDIAzPZQAORRqtJaOqT6BgzAFIrAWJGW8s6uwL4MNJ6Y3pjF7gDu1Km0EBDExUy8NEVp+MCcAL6cQA).

Is there a reason for this last odd behaviour or am I missing anything?

Comment: [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) aren't really a type safety feature, so their behavior is a bit strange and inconsistent.  But the specific issue where symbols of a non-literal type don't trigger excess property checks on a string index signature is apparently a known bug filed at [ms/TS#44794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44794).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Furthermore: you said "if I give `Symbol.iterator` it errors as expected" but [I don't see that](https://tsplay.dev/mxJdZw).  Could you either demonstrate that or remove it from the question?

Comment: @jcalz oh, I should have mentioned this behaviour is only for non `string` key types for that last example, I'd edit that last part. Also read about the excess type checks, but a brief reading, I'd read it properly after work

Comment: Ah, I see the `number` key type now.  That doesn't have anything to do with `Record<number, X>` per se; it's that computed properties don't trigger excess property checks at all, which is described at [ms/TS#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920).  I'll write *that* up as an answer, if you prefer.  I don't know if we want "all possible weirdnesses with `Record<K, V>`" as a single question though, so could you [edit] to let us know which is the primary question here?

Comment: @jcalz Ah I see, thank you, I edited it. The primary question was mostly with the keys being a `number` type, and the weirdness due to it (which I see now is not exactly related to just the `number` type). You should write this as an answer instead, and I'd look into the last ms/TS issue on this for general computed types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) in TypeScript is not really part of the type system.  It's a nice-to-have feature and not a type-safety feature.  It only happens in particular situations, and the lack of the feature outside these situations might be unfortunate, but it isn't a type safety hole.

Values are allowed to have more properties than required by their types; this is what enables interface and class hierarchies created via [extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) to act as *type* hierarchies.  Example:

```
interface Foo { fooProp: string }
interface Bar extends Foo { barProp: string }
const bar: Bar = { fooProp: "", barProp: "" };
const foo: Foo = bar; // okay
```

Every `Bar` is a valid `Foo`, even though the `Foo` type doesn't know about `barProp`.  If extra properties were prohibited, then `Bar` would not be compatible with `Foo`.

Instead, excess property checks are a linter-like feature that tries to prevent mistakes in which the compiler "forgets" about properties in [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
const otherFoo: Foo = { fooProp: "", barProp: "" }; // error!
// --------------------------------> ~~~~~~~
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, 
// and 'barProp' does not exist in type 'Foo'.(2322)
```

The reason why you get an error there isn't because `barProp` is "invalid" for a `Foo`; after all, the `foo` variable above has it.  It's because the compiler will forget all about `otherFoo`'s `barProp` property, and that might be a mistake.  That isn't the case for `foo`, since even though you can't access `foo.barProp` directly, you can access the same value via `bar.barProp`.

But again, excess property checking sometimes doesn't happen, even in object literals.

---

One such place excess property checking doesn't seem to happen is with [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920).  It is currently classified as a missing feature (although a similar issue was classified as a bug, so ‍♂️).

If the compiler cannot infer a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for a computed property, it tends to get widened to `string` or `number` or `symbol`, and is then simply ignored by excess property checks.  So while `otherFoo` above gets an excess property warning, the following does not:

```
const anotherFoo: Foo = {
  fooProp: "",
  ["bar" + "Prop"]: "" // no error
}
```

The compiler does not know that `"bar" + "Prop"` is of type `"barProp"` (it does not perform type-level string concatenation via the `+` operator); it only knows that it is of type `string`.  No excess property warning occurs, even though it is very unlikely for a random `string` to be one of the known keys of an interface.

The same thing happens with `symbol`-valued keys.  If the symbol is a known unique symbol, then you get an excess property warning:

```
const uniqueSymbol = Symbol("abc");

const yetAnotherFoo: Foo = {
  fooProp: "",
  [uniqueSymbol]: "" // error, excess prop
}
```

But if you have a non-unique symbol whose type is just `symbol`, you don't get an excess property warning:

```
const nonUniqueSymbol: symbol = uniqueSymbol;

const oneMoreForTheRoad: Foo = {
  fooProp: "",
  [nonUniqueSymbol]: "" // no error
}
```

That is why you're seeing the behavior with `Record<number, T>`.  Keys of type `number` are checked as expected, and literal-typed keys of non-`number` type in an object literal will get excess property warnings, but computed keys of widened, non-literal types do not.

A symbol key that is created inside a computed property isn't considered a unique symbol (you need to initialize a `const` with it, if you want it to be considered a unique symbol) and therefore treated as non-literal and you don't get a warning:

```
const a: Record<number, string> = {
  123: "", // okay
  [uniqueSymbol]: "", // error
  [Symbol.for("ephemeral and so not given a unique type")]: "" // okay
}
```

So that's the issue.  Excess property checking doesn't apply to computed properties of non-literal types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7JpgBSnQAcAuZAZzClAHNkBfAKFElkRQCE4pkIAHpBAATSmkw5kAI15FSFarRAMWCdCGozeFHnwC8U-OnnlkAInMAabVFMVLTANzN1msHkwUMWQ7KhOyAD0QcjoANZwAJ7Mrhpa6GAAFtA+3pKGuMb2Fta2OY6MgSH8UMRQAITMJQC0dfUNjU3NDQB8yAB+Xd0d1aHIyADy0gBWEAgeADbA7HCTyAC20WEgk1FUJOPAMOvhIOgA7iDIJMSbUGDAEJQ2fchwosgA5P6mT8gi6NfI+x6CwFpQMgwFFNs8fE8AHQACgATABmWGwgCUsTcWgeiRSUDSEl8OGYA2yZwc1kJyAA2uZ-OZkABqCymcwAXVJwVCyQByC5EWWAElkHQAK7XSgAfmYLDR8Q8QpAwAAjiKAMpRBbSdDzQyq9Wa6HmODSBDmZEuOLuZBRCBgACCv2xuJ8yEy5OJClyVnJFLlipVao1k1ZuXZpXKNkESEo4lOpEl0ot+xAAFV5UqIDqA4p-ZrncgfWmM5qzeiPBoIABZdBQCAYKAAFRSACV0HAROl8dhXYQSR6vYmU7709nA2ySpzxDzIusBcLRRKpSX7hRG+MqyIADwgIXq6A2JT0dougYARgRpJsJV5MQG3tTft1I49Ieg5S9hcmkPwUH1EBIKQW0BzPcjyUFgvyCsAABuEDHHAeZ3igIKbCaQaOJeU5xkAA)