# Object must only use keys from another object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Here is an example my object called `MY_OBJECT`:

```
export type ObjectDetails = {
    a: string,
    b?: string
};

export type MyObjectType = { [key: string]: ObjectDetails };

export const MY_OBJECT: MyObjectType = {
    BANANA: {
        a: "a"
    },
    LEMON: {
        a: "A"
    }
}

export type MyObjectKey = keyof typeof MY_OBJECT;
```

Now a method should return an object that uses keys in `MY_OBJECT` as keys (but doesn't have to use them all) and value can be a `string` or a `number`. So, I created this type:

```
type MyType = { [key: MyObjectKey]: string | number };
```

If I create this object and use a key NOT in `MY_OBJECT`, how do I have to modify my code so that it would throw a compilation error?

```
const newObject: MyType = {
    BANANA: "banana",
    APPLE: "apple" // <-- this should not compile
};
```

I think I understand correctly that it currently doesn't throw an error because I have set `MY_OBJECT` key type as `string` in `MyObjectType`. Do I really have to first create a type for all possible keys in `MY_OBJECT` and then use it in `MyObjectType`? I would like to not do that.

Comment: There are several problems here.  You annotated the type of `MY_OBJECT`, obliterating any info from the initializer; you might want `satisfies` instead.  Your `MyType` is invalid if you do that because index signatures cannot use a set of known keys; you should make it a mapped type instead.  Excess properties cannot generally be prohibited, only discouraged.  So, you can approach it as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpQBaW) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: In the playground, if you remove the `LEMON` it gives compiler error `Property 'LEMON' is missing in type '{ BANANA: string; }' but required in type 'MyType'.`. This was one criteria that object should not have to use all keys in `MY_OBJECT`.
    
 || > You annotated the type of MY_OBJECT, obliterating any info from the initializer.
I need values in `MY_OBJECT` to be of the type.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch the "don't have to use them all", just make the mapped type keys optional like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO2Y7W).  I don't understand your "I need values in `MY_OBJECT` to be of the type" comment.  `satisfies` should deal with that.  If it doesn't work the way you want, please [edit] the question to show the unmet use case.  If it does, I'll write up an answer.  Please let me know.

Comment: (see prev comment) just to make it clear, [this is what happens](https://tsplay.dev/mLJebw) if you make the value of the wrong type with `satisfies`.

Comment: This works as I hoped, thanks! I will think a bit more if I could do something to simplify my code though. Something doesn't feel right.

Comment: Is that something you're going to do offline after I answer the question? Or are you saying you're going to edit the question or something?  I just want to make sure that I'm not wasting time by starting to write up an answer.

Comment: I will do that offline. You can write up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that when you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable like `MY_OBJECT` with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type like `MyObjectType`, that's all the type checker will know about its type.  It won't remember any more specific information about the variable's initializer; such knowledge is lost forever.  So then `typeof MY_OBJECT` is just `MyObjectType`, and `keyof typeof MY_OBJECT` is just `string`.

Instead of annotating, you really just want to *check* that `MY_OBJECT`'s initializer is a valid `MyObjectType` without widening it all the way to `MyObjectType`.  That looks like a job for [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  If, instead of `const vbl: Type = expr` you write `const vbl = expr satisfies Type` you will often get more desirable behavior:

```
const MY_OBJECT = {
    BANANA: {
        a: "a"
    },
    LEMON: {
        a: "A"
    }
} satisfies MyObjectType // <-- do this instead
```

This still warns you if the initializer does not satisfy `MyObjectType`:

```
const MY_OBJECT = {
    BANANA: {
        a: "a"
    },
    LEMON: {
        a: 1 // error!
      //~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    }
} satisfies MyObjectType;
```

---

Now the type of `MY_OBJECT` is more specific than `MyObjectType`, which you can observe via IntelliSense:

```
/* const MY_OBJECT: {
    BANANA: { a: string; };
    LEMON: { a: string; };
} */
```

and you can get its keys as desired:

```
type MyObjectKey = keyof typeof MY_OBJECT;
// type MyObjectKey = "BANANA" | "LEMON"
```

---

Now you can define `MyType` accordingly.  You can't use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) for this purpose; index signatures only support "wide" types like `string`. You have a set of known keys.  You should use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) instead.  Since you want the properties to be optional, you can use the `?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
type MyType = { [K in MyObjectKey]?: string | number }; 
/* type MyType = {
    BANANA?: string | number | undefined;
    LEMON?: string | number | undefined;
} */
```

And now you'll get the behavior you were looking for:

```
const newObject: MyType = {
    BANANA: "banana",
    APPLE: "apple" // <-- error
};
```

---

A final caveat, though. [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) like the error on `APPLE` above only happen when you use an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) directly in a place expecting a type without the property.  They are mostly a linter warning that you might be making a mistake by have made a mistake  by using a key the compiler will immediately forget about.  They are not intended to be a type error, and you can always evade the detection by doing the assignment in multiple steps, like this:

```
const obj = { BANANA: "banana", APPLE: "apple" };
const newObject2: MyType = obj; // this will never be an error.
```

That's fine according to the compiler because `obj` knows about `APPLE`.  This is sort of out of scope here, since everything works as you wanted.  But you should be aware of it anyway.  See [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299/2887218) or [Why are excess properties allowed in Typescript when all properties in an interface are optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59228227/2887218) or [typescript: validate excess keys on value, returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263271/2887218) or [Unexpected behaviour of Typescript Record<number, Type> type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76701297/2887218), or any other question mentioning "excess properties" and "TypeScript", for more.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AEQsAhgSwDYDOUAvFAN4BQU1UWAXFAcAE44B2A5gDRU1wD8DJq04UAvgG4KFUJCgBZEPCSoAKuGikyUANoBrCCCEt2HALoNlKdJlyEok6cgD2bJgoCaAfRgAhAFIAogDCqiTkvNS+AIIAcnHRDJQ0KbQMAERY6ZEOPCkAMoHyMLFJOSn0UOnR2Sli4oxYwDgEAGY4EESKVmoaUAD0-VAAPAC0o1AAJs5QwAAWLVDsTBBYk9L9AFRQLm7Anj4BIaplKTHx8UlpjCacEg5SBUUlV5XCpveOYlCb-U6u7hiaC88m8fiCoXCyRo5wSp1S1EqmVqNDEeRohWKpQiCMRDAAjAMhhBmMxnMwAITlGiDAB+I3GUHUcgA5GwAK4AWzgJJZSyIbGc+ywBAIOA4bCwcDw0GAM1k0BZ704LIAdDl6t8CE0Wu1OgolIhrMzoIMGRNprMFkRlsBVutpAqDT1gABpQzhAwgZytWYaH0HcHHKRmp3dI2od0gcLpWHxdJQAA+VUxJWyMj6ihNUN0rqWbGdEbdhjMghuIg4SagHO5JIeRPNVsWiywUE5WDAkEmfsgFC2PegWb6WhyceiZeVleTNZ5zCr7LYkwg7TYEEmjwxz1iE9uU+rXNn88Xy-Ya6k31+-z21YgAHcXQwh3IR2cEpcqnAsJLJel0dRogACgBhQZB2YAygmZpjBMJJksw4hSH2QxwOy+wQAAHsgnREGAZKQMwzT6lgzDQLEMBhK2TqweSjAzN67I7F+tB4LeWAgEQBCrlgehWhAnL5lAeA4AYdAULs7jOIgOZjhkn7flkXBQIBwGBKBnYQQ8YkAvsq73kWABMj4gNmpCSQg9yhtaUC3vgeA3gAbnWPK0AW1HMKqQA)

Comment: Thank you! But I did some changes: [playground](https://shorturl.at/pBR78). There is one drawback that I brought out, but it is okay for me because I will never use all original keys at once.